# How can I translate LVDS to LVTTL with limitations?

Tags: operational-amplifier, lvds

I want to convert LVDS differential signals to LVTTL.
I have 2 limitations:

1. The frequency of the LVDS signal is around 500 MHz.
2. The LVTTL voltage output should be around 2.4 V and it needs to drive a 50 Ω resistor.

From a simple calculation 2.4 V/50 Ω=48 mA is the current drive capability of the LVTTL output.

I have been looking at chips that can do the conversion from LVDS to LVTTL but none of them support such frequencies or drive 48 mA.

Any suggestions on how to solve it? Any ideas

Update question:

If I take the LVDS clock differential and connect it to a differential output amplifier, this amplifier is LMH5401 and it has 2 output, I will take one output and then I need to find a circuit to drive the 48 mA, what do you think about this solution?

Comment: Why does it have to drive a 50 Ohm resistor? That sounds a lot like a terminated piece of coax. Are you able to use a higher impedance coax?

Comment: this is actually a requirement , cant change it .

Comment: Lvds receiver followed by a 50 ohm line driver.

Comment: @user1850479 can you explain , what do you mean ?

Comment: Add a buffer after the LVDS to LVTTL converter.  Something like an ACT240, only faster.  Have you done a parameter search on some of the manufacturer's web sites, like TI?

Comment: How far is it to the 50 ohm resistor?

Comment: @SteveSh , the issue is that the chip converter cant stand such frequencies , they have high rise and fall time of more than 1ns , now imagine the wave of the LVDS has 2ns cycle , then i will not have a time to keep the signal on high level for example .
so the i will still have an issue even if i use a buffer after that can drive 48mA
regarding how far the 50ohm imaging it is not far

Comment: Is it a clock, or a random signal?

Comment: The SN65LVDS2 LVDS to TTL converter is pretty close to what you need.  If the load isn't too capacitive, the rise time is in the hundreds of picoseconds, although you'll be limited to ~1.8V into a 50 ohm load.  If you could live with that its a very simple solution.

Comment: This sounds more like an RF power amplifier application than a logic clock application. Have you considered an MMIC or RF power transistor? (I use "power" loosely here; ~20dBm straddles the line between a strong preamp and a small power amp. A class A amplifier will dissipate a bit under a watt here.)

Comment: @bobflux clock signals .

Comment: @user1850479 I see in data sheet that the SN65LVDS2 has rise time / fall time of 1ns and this is not good since the cycle of lvds is 2ns (500mhz) … so I will still have the problem

Comment: Have you looked at clock driver or clock distribution ICs?   They're  plenty fast enough, but most seem to have diff outputs, not LVTTL that you asked for.

Comment: Clock buffer chip with about 10x differential outputs all wired in parallel + transformer? Needs low skew.

Comment: The typical SN65LVDS2 rise/fall time is 800ps, but that depends on load capacitance, so you might do better since you're driving a line and not a gate capacitance (see datasheet figures for an idea). If you want even faster, you'll probably need to use a line driver IC or RF part.

Comment: @SteveSh , can you give me some example of this clock buffer chip ?
if all the outputs are diff , i can use only one output and then bias to some DC level  to reach the 2.4V of LVTTL output 
for example if this buffer output LVDS and i have the 50ohm resistor in the output , the 3.5mA drive from the LVDS will built an AC voltage over the 50ohm and i will bias it to some dc level

Comment: hi guys , i wrote an update can you look on it and give me feedback ?

Comment: Welcome! Please improve your punctuation. Free plugins are available for every browser for the very purpose. _”what do you think about this solution?”_ is soliciting for opinions. Instead, state your requirements and it will become much easier to answer if your proposal will meet your requirements or not. Please draw a schematic.